# Pass an new undefined object extending an interface in php

Tags: php, oop

Does someone know if it is possible to pass an undefined object extending a defined interface in php into a function:

For example something in this form:

```
callFunction(new InterfaceName {

    public function interfaceMethod() {
        // do something
    }

});
```

Comment: How is an undefined object supposed to implement an Interface? Additionally, `{}` does not create an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no such thing as 'object, which implements interface'. Class can implement interface, while object can be an instance of this class. So you have to define the corresponding class and then instantiate it:

```
class Foo implements InterfaceX { /*..*/ }
//...
callFunction(new Foo);
```

-however, just for the information - about anonymous classes - there is an [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/anonymous_classes) with such functionality, suggested by [Joe Watkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1658631/joe-watkins) - but it was rejected by PHP internals community for now.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your quick response i've also modified the question to give a more clear idea of the concept.

Comment: @user1169526 the answer is in RFC, link on which I've provided. To be short: _yes_ such thought exists, but _no_ it's impossible right now